# How should I configure Nginx to maximise the throughput for single Ruby application running on Passenger?

Tags: nginx, config, passenger, benchmarking

I want to benchmark Nginx+Passenger, and am wondering if there is anything that can be adjusted in the following `nginx.conf` to improve throughput and reduce latency. This is running on a 4-core i7 (8 hardware threads) with 16GB of main memory.

```
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_passenger_module.so;

# One per CPU core:
worker_processes auto;

events {
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log off;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 60;

    # 8 should be number of CPU threads.
    passenger_root /usr/lib/passenger;
    passenger_max_pool_size 8;

    server {
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name passenger;

        root /srv/http/benchmark/public;

        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_min_instances 8;
        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
        passenger_sticky_sessions on;
    }
}
```

I am using `wrk` with multiple concurrent connections (e.g. 100).

Here are some specific issues:

- Can the Nginx configuration be improved further?

  - Is it using HTTP/1.1 persistent connections to the Passenger application servers?
  - Is using a dynamic module causing any performance issues?
  - Do I need to do anything else to maximise the efficiency of how the integration is working?
  - I haven't set a passenger log file to ensure that logging IO is not a bottleneck.
- Regarding the number of processes - I have 8 hardware threads, so I’ve set it to use 8 instances minimum.

  - Would it make sense to use threads per application server? I assume it's only relevant for IO bound workloads.
  - If I am pegging the processors with 8 application servers, does that indicate a sufficient amount of servers? Or should I try with, say, 16?
- What is the expected performance difference between Nginx+Passenger vs Passenger Standalone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passenger dev here.

> "Can the Nginx configuration be improved further?"

Probably, Nginx has a lot of levers, and if all you are doing is serving known payloads in a benchmark then you can seriously improve performance with Nginx's caching, for example.

> "Is it using HTTP/1.1 persistent connections to the Passenger application servers?"

No it uses unix sockets.

> "Is using a dynamic module causing any performance issues?"

No, once nginx loads the library, making a function call into it is the same as any other c++ function call.

> "Do I need to do anything else to maximize the efficiency of how the integration is working?"

You might want to look into Passenger's turbo caching, and/or nginx caching.

> "I haven't set a passenger log file to ensure that logging IO is not a bottleneck."

Good, but turn the logging level down to 0 to avoid a bit of processing.

> "Would it make sense to use threads per application server? I assume it's only relevant for IO bound workloads."

Not sure exactly what you mean, are you talking about Passenger's multithreading support or nginx's?

> "If I am pegging the processors with 8 application servers, does that indicate a sufficient amount of servers?"

If you are CPU bound then adding more processes won't help.

> "What is the expected performance difference between Nginx+Passenger vs Passenger Standalone?"

Not much, Passenger standalone uses nginx internally. You might see some improvement if you use the builtin engine with passenger standalone, but that means you can't use caching which is far more important.